# Laravel3: How to check if there is a file uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I have a page with a form where user can upload an image to replace his existing avatar.

However, if the user submits forms without uploading an image, I will not update his avatar and user can keep his old avatar.

This is an UPDATE issue so I need something like this in pseudo code:

```
if (Input::has_uploaded_file() === true)
    //User uploaded something, update avatar column/remove old avatar etc.
else
    //User didn't upload anything so don't update avatar column
```

I just need the first line, though.

Can anybody help? I couldn't find much about this in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Input::has_file('name')` does not work for you then you can use the equivalent of what it is doing, like this...

```
if (Input::file('name.tmp_name', '') != '')
```

*Taken from [laravel/input.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/input.php#L211)*

Answer (score 0):

I read laravel source code, i think its this:

```
Input::has_file('input_name');
```

If that's not work, try using native php:

```
$_FILES['input_name']['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE;
```

Or same above with laravel:

```
$i = Input::file('input_name');

$i['error'] = UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE;
```

Code above is to check if user leave the upload form empty.

Comment: UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE means user leave the form empty. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php